# Is there a way to get data out of Age of Empires 3's view postgame?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

It's been a while since I started playing Age of Empires 3 online. Is there a way to get the timelines (and other data found in the postgame, such as resource gathering, experience...) out of the game for proper examination?

More info: I play on a macbook pro.

Answer (score 1):

If it is true that you are indeed online, then i would refer you to this link

```
http://aoe3.jpcommunity.com/rating2/
```

Look up your IGN and you will find your past games. That should be as close to post game stats as you can get. Do note that detailed stats and graphs are only kept for a duration before its removed.

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm playing in a "wined" version of AoE3 for mac. Still have the CD for PC, though.

Comment: I would have thought that data are stored server side if you are playing on the ladder. Never heard of wine but from what i can see it just adds a compatibility layer. Not sure how this affects things.

Comment: You can only play via GameRanger. I don't believe there's a ladder there.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the super-low-tech method of taking screenshots of all the output screens, then typing the data from the screenshots into the spreadsheet by hand.  Not an ideal solution for sure, but if the data you are looking for isn't actually in a file you can get access to, it may be the only choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use certain software to read out your ram memory.
For example, CheatEngine does this to modify values in your game (i.e. cheat).
Other software like it may be able to read the memory and export the data.

The problem is that you'll need to find the locations where it's stored in memory, which won't be easy to find. (Can't really help you there)